# Raspberry Pi OOM Kill

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, feh

I am trying to create a Python script that will act like a digital picture frame, running on Raspberry Pi Zero, hooked up to a monitor. I managed to get the script to work for my requirements. However, I am running into issue with memory management, because the process of the script keeps getting killed because OOM.

```
Dec 14 15:55:25 raspberrypi kernel: [ 2987.175293] oom-kill:constraint=CONSTRAINT_NONE,nodemask=(null),global_oom,task_memcg=/,task=python,pid=1759,uid=1000
Dec 14 15:55:25 raspberrypi kernel: [ 2987.175357] Out of memory: Killed process 1759 (python) total-vm:273328kB, anon-rss:250680kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB, UID:1000 pgtables:276kB oom_score_adj:0
```

I barely worked with Python before so I don't really know a lot about how Python manages memory. Below is my script:

```
from PIL import Image
import os
import random
import subprocess
import time
import signal

def scan_images(image_dir):
    print("scanning images")
    image_files = []
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(image_dir):
        for file in files:
            if file.lower().endswith(('.png', '.jpg', '.jpeg')):
                image_files.append(os.path.join(root, file))
    print("finished scanning")
    return image_files

def create_slideshow(image_dir):
    # Register a signal handler for interrupt (Ctrl+C)
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)

    try:
        os.environ['DISPLAY'] = ':0.0'
        image_files = scan_images(image_dir)
        vertical_images = [img for img in image_files if Image.open(os.path.join(image_dir, img)).height > Image.open(os.path.join(image_dir, img)).width]
        horizontal_images = [img for img in image_files if Image.open(os.path.join(image_dir, img)).width >= Image.open(os.path.join(image_dir, img)).height]
        random.shuffle(vertical_images)
        print("found {} vertical images".format(len(vertical_images)))
        random.shuffle(horizontal_images)
        print("found {} horizontal images".format(len(horizontal_images)))

        feh_current_process = None
        feh_previous_process = None

        while True:
            # Display horizontal images on their own
            for horizontal_image in horizontal_images:
            # Launch new feh process
                print("executing command")
                feh_previous_process = feh_current_process
                feh_current_process = subprocess.Popen(['feh', '--fullscreen', '--auto-zoom', '--hide-pointer', os.path.join(image_dir, horizontal_image)])

                # Pause for a few seconds (adjust as needed)
                print("sleeping 5 sec")
                time.sleep(5)

                # terminate old feh
                print("terminate old feh")
                if feh_previous_process != None:
                    feh_previous_process.terminate()
                
                # Pause for a few seconds (adjust as needed)
                print("sleeping 5 sec")
                time.sleep(5)
            # Display paired vertical images with an additional vertical image on the right side
            for i in range(0, len(vertical_images)):
                # Select vertical image
                current_vertical_image = vertical_images[i]

                # Select one additional random vertical image for the right side
                additional_vertical_image = random.choice(vertical_images)

                # Create composite image with two vertical images side by side
                composite_image_path = os.path.join(image_dir, 'composite_image.jpg')
                create_composite_image(image_dir, current_vertical_image, additional_vertical_image, composite_image_path)

                # Display the composite image in the background
                display_command = ['feh', '--fullscreen', '--auto-zoom', '--hide-pointer', composite_image_path]
                print("executing command {}".format(display_command))
                feh_previous_process = feh_current_process
                feh_current_process = subprocess.Popen(display_command)

                # Pause for a few seconds (adjust as needed)
                print("sleeping 5 sec")
                time.sleep(5)

                # terminate old feh
                print("terminate old feh")
                if feh_previous_process != None:
                    feh_previous_process.terminate()
                
                # Pause for a few seconds (adjust as needed)
                print("sleeping 5 sec")
                time.sleep(5)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Slideshow interrupted. Cleaning up...")
        cleanup()

def signal_handler(sig, frame):
    # Handle interrupt signal (Ctrl+C)
    raise KeyboardInterrupt

def cleanup():
    # Additional cleanup steps if needed
    sys.exit(0)
    
def create_composite_image(image_dir, image1, image2, output_path):
    img1 = Image.open(os.path.join(image_dir, image1))
    img2 = Image.open(os.path.join(image_dir, image2))

    # Resize both vertical images to the height of the taller one
    max_height = max(img1.height, img2.height)
    img1 = img1.resize((int(img1.width * max_height / img1.height), max_height))
    img2 = img2.resize((int(img2.width * max_height / img2.height), max_height))

    # Create a new image with double width for vertical images
    composite_img = Image.new('RGB', (img1.width + img2.width, max_height))
    composite_img.paste(img1, (0, 0))
    composite_img.paste(img2, (img1.width, 0))

    # Save the composite image
    composite_img.save(output_path)
    img1.close()
    img2.close()
    composite_img.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    if len(sys.argv) != 2:
        print("Usage: python slideshow.py /path/to/image/directory")
        sys.exit(1)

    image_directory = sys.argv[1]

    if not os.path.isdir(image_directory):
        print(f"Error: {image_directory} is not a valid directory.")
        sys.exit(1)

    create_slideshow(image_directory)
```

Clearly I am brute forcing my way through this. But my thinking is if I clear things correctly, then the memory usage should stay constant, and if the script can display the first dozen images without any issue, then it should be able to continue to do so, if I clear things correctly right? The only thing I could think of is to close the Image I opened to modify and terminate old process. I surely miss something here. Can anyone see it?

Comment: How many images do you have in the directory? What is the resolution? You seem to load all the images at the same time. Try lazy loading.

Comment: I have a couple hundreds and resolution varies, some can go up to around 2000x3000. But that should not matter right? Because most of the time I will just be referencing the path to the image and not the image itself. The only place I actually load in the image is when I open a vertical image to composite it with another vertical image and then close them both afterward.

Comment: Yes. Multiply 2000*3000*200BThat's well above a GB. Don't open all the images. Instead only open the once you are displaying and then close them once you are done.

Comment: That is what I am doing right...?

Comment: I don't think so. In create slideshow you open every image that satisfies a height and width criteria and store it in a list. Now I don't know how many images would those be. But if they are taken from a phone camera most of them would have the save size so you probably open all of them

Answer (score 0):

I think, this should help:

1. You should close image after getting dimensions to prevent loading all the images into RAM simultaneously.
2. Consider using context managers to close them automatically (`with Image.open(...) as image: ...`)

Note changes in `create_slideshow()`, `create_composite_image()` and take a look into the new function - `read_image_resolution()`.

```py
from PIL import Image
import os
import random
import subprocess
import time
import signal


def scan_images(image_dir):
    print("scanning images")
    image_files = []
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(image_dir):
        for file in files:
            if file.lower().endswith(('.png', '.jpg', '.jpeg')):
                image_files.append(os.path.join(root, file))
    print("finished scanning")
    return image_files


def read_image_resolution(image_file_path):
    with Image.open(image_file_path) as img:
        return (img.width, img.height)


def create_slideshow(image_dir):
    # Register a signal handler for interrupt (Ctrl+C)
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)

    try:
        os.environ['DISPLAY'] = ':0.0'
        image_files = scan_images(image_dir)

        vertical_images = []
        horizontal_images = []

        for image in image_files:
            image_file_path = os.path.join(image_dir, image)
            w, h = read_image_resolution(image_file_path)
            if w > h:
                horizontal_images.append(image_file_path)
            else:
                vertical_images.append(image_file_path)

        random.shuffle(vertical_images)
        print("found {} vertical images".format(len(vertical_images)))
        random.shuffle(horizontal_images)
        print("found {} horizontal images".format(len(horizontal_images)))

        feh_current_process = None
        feh_previous_process = None

        while True:
            # Display horizontal images on their own
            for horizontal_image in horizontal_images:
            # Launch new feh process
                print("executing command")
                feh_previous_process = feh_current_process
                feh_current_process = subprocess.Popen(['feh', '--fullscreen', '--auto-zoom', '--hide-pointer', horizontal_image])

                # Pause for a few seconds (adjust as needed)
                print("sleeping 5 sec")
                time.sleep(5)

                # terminate old feh
                print("terminate old feh")
                if feh_previous_process != None:
                    feh_previous_process.terminate()
                
                # Pause for a few seconds (adjust as needed)
                print("sleeping 5 sec")
                time.sleep(5)
            # Display paired vertical images with an additional vertical image on the right side
            for i in range(0, len(vertical_images)):
                # Select vertical image
                current_vertical_image = vertical_images[i]

                # Select one additional random vertical image for the right side
                additional_vertical_image = random.choice(vertical_images)

                # Create composite image with two vertical images side by side
                composite_image_path = os.path.join(image_dir, 'composite_image.jpg')
                create_composite_image(current_vertical_image, additional_vertical_image, composite_image_path)

                # Display the composite image in the background
                display_command = ['feh', '--fullscreen', '--auto-zoom', '--hide-pointer', composite_image_path]
                print("executing command {}".format(display_command))
                feh_previous_process = feh_current_process
                feh_current_process = subprocess.Popen(display_command)

                # Pause for a few seconds (adjust as needed)
                print("sleeping 5 sec")
                time.sleep(5)

                # terminate old feh
                print("terminate old feh")
                if feh_previous_process != None:
                    feh_previous_process.terminate()
                
                # Pause for a few seconds (adjust as needed)
                print("sleeping 5 sec")
                time.sleep(5)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Slideshow interrupted. Cleaning up...")
        cleanup()


def signal_handler(sig, frame):
    # Handle interrupt signal (Ctrl+C)
    raise KeyboardInterrupt


def cleanup():
    # Additional cleanup steps if needed
    sys.exit(0)


def create_composite_image(image1, image2, output_path):
    with Image.open(image1) as img1, \
         Image.open(image2) as img2:
         
        # Resize both vertical images to the height of the taller one
        max_height = max(img1.height, img2.height)
        img1 = img1.resize((int(img1.width * max_height / img1.height), max_height))
        img2 = img2.resize((int(img2.width * max_height / img2.height), max_height))

        # Create a new image with double width for vertical images
        with Image.new('RGB', (img1.width + img2.width, max_height)) as composite_img:

            composite_img.paste(img1, (0, 0))
            composite_img.paste(img2, (img1.width, 0))

            # Save the composite image
            composite_img.save(output_path)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    if len(sys.argv) != 2:
        print("Usage: python slideshow.py /path/to/image/directory")
        sys.exit(1)

    image_directory = sys.argv[1]

    if not os.path.isdir(image_directory):
        print(f"Error: {image_directory} is not a valid directory.")
        sys.exit(1)

    create_slideshow(image_directory)
```